# Checking whether given array is sorted by divide-and-conquer

Tags: java, algorithm, array, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I've written a code that I try to use divide and conquer approach to determine if the given array is sorted. I wonder whether I apply the approach accurately.

```
public static boolean isSorted(List<Integer> arr, int start, int end) {
    if (end - start == 1) // base case to compare two elements
        return arr.get(end) > arr.get(start);

    int middle = (end + start) >>> 1; // division by two
    boolean leftPart = isSorted(arr, start, middle);
    boolean rightPart = isSorted(arr, middle, end);
    return leftPart && rightPart;
}
```

To use call,

```
isSorted(list, 0, list.size() - 1)
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Test your code on `3, 4, 1, 2`.

Comment: @vnp `isSorted(list, 0, 3)` will call `isSorted(arr, 1, 3)` which will call `isSorted(arr, 1, 2)` which will return `false`.  That test case is fine.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your are doing it mostly right.   You have problems with length zero and length 1 arrays, but you should be able to fix those pretty quick.

You may be doing more work than necessary.  If an array is not sorted, you might find `leftPart` is `false`, but you unconditionally go on to determine the value of `rightPart` anyway, despite it not mattering.  The simplest way to avoid that is to combine that recursive calls and the `&&` operation.  Ie:

```
return isSorted(arr, start, middle) && isSorted(arr, middle, end);
```

Lastly, if the array contains duplicates, can it still be considered sorted?  You return `false` for `[1, 2, 2, 3]`.